# How can I capture php session variables in javascript without page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session

I have an `index.php`, where I do `session_start()` etc. For login, I send an ajax request to `receiver.php`, where I set the session variables etc and get an ajax response back.

Now, I can perfectly capture the php session variables ***only when I refresh*** the `index.php` page that has the following code:

```
jsSessionUserId = <?php     
    if (isset($_SESSION['userId'])) { //LoggedIn:
        echo json_encode($_SESSION['userId']); 
    } else { //  Not logged in.
        // some code here
    }
?>;
```

What I really want is to put this in a function and then call this function when I receive a successful ajax response (and thus not have the need to refresh the `index.php` page). It is not working. I suspect that the php doesn't quite work inside of a javascript function. Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is bad idea to mix things up. Like php and javascript. Easiest solution for you right now - overwrite your javascript variables once successful login response is received.

```
$.post("receiver.php", formData, function(response){ // login callback
  if(response.UserId){ // return user id if login is successful
    jsSessionUserId = response.UserId; // overwrite old variable
  }
}, "json");
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried your concept and I no longer need to mix php and javascript. The ajax call is done on an button/image click (no form involved), then upon return it updates jsSessionUserId. And I avoided using a global variable like jsSessionUserId using closure (Crockford - the good parts kind of stuff). This is good enough solution for me at this moment, but if there are better ways, please enlighten.