# Get current session variable without page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session-variables

my problem is as follows (Question updated):

I've got two pages:

**1.php** and **2.php**

I'm trying to get a *PHP* variable (in this very case, a SESSION variable) from *2.php* to *1.php* through an *AJAX* request.

This is the script in *1.php*

```
jQuery('#refresh').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: '2.php',
        data: { sessionVar: '<?php $PHPvariable ?>' },
        success:function(response){
            alert(sessionVar);
        }
    })
});
```

For your better understanding, this script is called from within the *1.php* file, so to properly inject PHP into the js.
As you can see I'm trying to retreive the **$PHPvariable** variable declared in *2.php*.

Am I doing it correctly??

Comment: Please fix your code. there is no snippet there.

Comment: Without refresh current page. No choice, you should use javascript.

Comment: Yes, I got that, but how? :)

Comment: you can do it using js
see
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19119274/how-can-i-capture-php-session-variables-in-javascript-without-page-refresh)

Comment: not using an appropriate tool for a certain job, because not knowing it at a certain point is no excuse, you'd better learn it. At least it's better for you, otherwise you will remain with the knowledge of only making `1.php` and `2.php` till the end of your entire life...

Comment: So NOT knowing how-to is forbidden. And asking for help even worse...
I'm not asking you to do my job. I tried all day long yesterday, and on the web I couldn't find eanugh clues to get it to work...
In addition to that I'm Italian and sometimes I find hard to understand English tutorials...
I'm trying to learn things by my self, and you are judging me. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, because your question is `I'm using wood to beat nails, but one nail is too big, and I cannot beat it enough to get there, I tried to beat them with a hammer, but unfortunately I couldn't manage, because I do not know how to use hammer. Maybe there's another way`; No, you'd better use a hammer, instead of heavier wood. Having hard time to understand english terms is also good thing, because you will improve your english while trying to understand the terms. So, I'm judging you for the thing you want to find a workaround instead of using the right tool

Comment: As you can see, I've updated the question, and tried to clarify it as much as possible...

Comment: you have to alert not the data you have posted (sessionvar), but the response. And to display something, you need to echo it, `<?php $var; ?>` has nothing to print

Answer (score 0):

Example with JQuery

In 1.php

```
$.ajax({
  url: "2.php"
})
.done(function( data ) {
  // data should return your variable
});
```

See here for more : [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11911779/get-a-php-session-variable-from-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is make jquery call php file which will get your session value:

```
function GetSessionValue(sesname){

        $.post("getsession.php", {sesname: ""+sesname+""}, function(data){
            if(data.length >0) {
               //do what you want with your session value
            }
        });

}
```

and in your php file write only

```
$sesname = $_POST['sesname'];
echo $_SESSION[$sesname];
```